# Does data changes in DB if we use lookup function in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Does data change in DB if we use the `lookup function in MongoDB`

I used below code:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([{ $lookup: { from: "colllection2", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "new" } }])
```

Comment: `aggregate` can save documents, `$lookup` or not. This one doesn't.

Comment: Can you please help me change the query just to retrieve data from collections based on "_id" value but not change any data or create any new collections in DB?